# Can't install LAMP and can't run tasksel

Tags: lamp, tasksel

I can't get LAMP installed and I can't get TASKSEL to run. This is really becoming a drag now.

my input for installing LAMP: `sudo apt-get install lamp-server`
output:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2 : Conflicts: apache2.2-common but 2.2.22-6ubuntu5 is to be installed
 apache2-bin : Conflicts: apache2.2-common but 2.2.22-6ubuntu5 is to be installed
 apache2-data : Conflicts: apache2.2-common but 2.2.22-6ubuntu5 is to be installed
 apache2.2-common : Depends: apache2.2-bin (= 2.2.22-6ubuntu5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
my input for running tasksel: sudo tasksel
next the interface (the familiar text based ui) starts and after selecting the progress bar starts. But then unexpected it breaks of (drops out of the ui)
with this message:
tasksel: aptitude failed (100)
```

now I search a lot and tried them all: "uninstalling apache" (none installed), "try to find broken packages" (none), "purge", "remove", etc.

Anyone a clue? Or after all these years I'm still a noob who's better off using windows? (Hope not.)
I'm considering making a fresh ubuntu reinstall, but that too is a drag. Besides it will make me feel like an idiot even more than I do right now.   (well,   ;)   )

```
$ apt-cache policy apache2
apache2:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1
  Version table:
     2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1 0
        500 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.4.7-1ubuntu4 0
        500 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/main amd64 Packages
     2.2.22-6ubuntu5 0
        500 old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring/main amd64 Packages 

$ lsb_release -a LSB Version: core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-‌​amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noar‌​ch:core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:security-4.0-amd64:security-4.0-noarch:security‌​-4.1-amd64:security-4.1-noarch Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS Release: 14.04 Codename: trusty –
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `apt-cache policy apache2` and `lsb_release -a` in your question. Apache 2.2.22-6ubuntu5 was only [present in Ubuntu raring](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/apache2) which has reached now end-of-life for a long time already. Please include the output of the commands to confirm you're running Raring still.

Comment: I have not installed anything of the kind. it must have come along with some other package/application.

Comment: Apparently you have a `raring` repository set up on a `trusty` system. You don't really want that after you finished the upgrade. Please include more information in how you got your system in this state. Any particular upgrade path for example? Or are you deliberately using the raring repositories for some reason?

Comment: like i already said: I have not installed anything of the kind. it must have come along with some else. I upgraded this version just a couple of months ago. Upgrading from 12.04. For some reason this one doesn't run half as smooth as 1204. Neither did ubuntu 13 btw.
What upgrade are you referring to?<br><br>
(ad.) possible it was installed when in installed virtualbox

Comment: You have held broken packages which need to be fixed first before you can install new packages the normal way (see [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](/q/140246/175814)).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will fix it, but at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP they say you should use it with a caret (^), that worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

Answer (score -2):

just run

```
apt-get update
```

and try again. Worked for me.

Comment: -1 That command cannot fix broken or held packages.

Comment: `sudo apt-get -f install`  can fix dependencies!